# Why does Windows KB hotfixes contain 2 different versions of the same file?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-update

why does Windows KB hotfixes contain 2 different versions of the same file?

Take for example the kernel file in this update:

```
+++ MS13-017 +++

|--[NTOSKRNL.EXE 6.1.7600.17207 (x86/x86)
|--[NTOSKRNL.EXE 6.1.7601.18044 (x86/x86)
|--[NTOSKRNL.EXE 6.1.7601.22210 (x86/x86)
```

Seems like the first one is for SP0 (.7600), but 2 others are for SP1. So why there's 2 versions for SP1 Windows? And why their versions (.18044 / .22210) differ so much?

Comment: We often (sadly) have to create multiple DLL's (The same dll but a different version) for our software based upon individual client's requirements... I would *guess*, the same reason applies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Microsoft at  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2799494 and others:

```
    GDR service branches contain only those fixes that are widely
 released to address widespread, critical issues. LDR service 
 branches contain hotfixes in addition to widely released fixes.
```

For Windows 7 & Server 2008, these are:

```
6.1.7600.16xxx  Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2    RTM GDR
6.1.7600.20xxx  Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2    RTM LDR
6.1.7601.17xxx  Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2    SP1 GDR
6.1.7601.21xxx  Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2    SP1 LDR
```

So for X86 versions of Win7 -- depending on installed hotfixes -- you could have possibly any of:

```
Ntoskrnl.exe    6.1.7600.17207  3,902,312   05-Jan-2013 05:02
Ntoskrnl.exe    6.1.7600.21417  3,915,112   05-Jan-2013 04:53
Ntoskrnl.exe    6.1.7601.18044  3,913,064   05-Jan-2013 05:00
Ntoskrnl.exe    6.1.7601.22210  3,916,648   05-Jan-2013 04:49
```

Comment: Thanks! Found also good explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13026090/windows-updates-gdr-vs-ldr-qfe

Comment: Most installs only apply patches; the others are for systems that have applied hotfixes. So without knowing the update history, you wouldn't know which one. Only the "Patches and updates" are generally installed automatically via Windows Update - i.e. critical fixes -- while hotfixes have to be selected and managed by the user.